# Калькулятор на JS + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Доброго времени суток, я начинающий программист. Столкнулся с довольно обычной задачей, но из-за нехватки опыта не могу понять в каком направлении идти.

Мне нужно написать обычный js + php калькулятор для подсчета суммы заказа по коэффициентам.

Вот [тут](https://dving.ru/content/prokachka-reytinga-dota-2) находится похожий калькулятор (как пример):

С фронтенд частью калькулятора и передачей двух числовых переменных ползунков "Мой рейтинг" и "Хочу рейтинг", через ajax в php обработчик - я разобрался.

Но с подсчетом итоговой суммы рублей в php обработчике, у меня возникли сложности.

Я написал формулу (для теста), по которой можно было бы посчитать переменные вручную, но как это воплотить с точки зрения логики php, я не знаю.

```
//Получили положение ползунков (для примера)
$current_mmr = 1000; //Мой рейтинг
$end_mmr = 5000; //Хочу рейтинг

//Находим расстояние между ползунками
$value = $end_mmr - $current_mmr;

$a = (2500 - $current_mmr) * 2;
$b = (3500 - 2500) * 2.5;
$c = (4500 - 3500) * 3.5;
$d = ($end_mmr - 4500) * 5.5;

$e = $a + $b + $c + $d;

//Получаем средний коэффициент
$f = $e / $value;

//Умножаем расстояние между ползунками на средний коэффициент
$result = $value * $f;

$html = "Итого: {$result}.руб";

echo json_encode(array('result' => 'success', 'html' => $html));
```

Сложность заключается в том, что у каждого числового диапазона свой коэффициент умножения:

```
0-2500 value=2
2500-3500 value=2.5
3500-4500 value=3.5
4500-5500 value=5.5
```

Вот логика по которой я писал алгоритм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Дано:

1)"Дистанция" от 0 до 5500

    2)Коэффициенты умножения на "промежутках" дистанции:
        a) от 0 до 2500 * 2
        b) от 2500 до 3500 * 2.5
        c) от 3500 до 4500 * 3.5
        d) от 4500 до 5500 * 5.5

3) Две переменных: a, b (Наши ползунки "Текущий ММР" и "Конечный ММР")
4) const = a < b (Ползунок "Конечный ММР" всегда больше чем "Текущий ММР")

Например нам через ajax передались такие значения:

a = 1000 "Текущий ММР"
b = 5000 "Конечный ММР"

Найти:

Общую стоимость за каждую единицу "дистанции" от точки a до точки b, умноженную на коэффициенты по отношению к своим "промежуткам" на дистации.

Решение:

1)Найти промежуток дистации между a и b

b - a = 4000 (Промежуток между ползунками "Текущий ММР" и "Конечный ММР" - это ММР который нужно забустить)

2)

    a)2500 - 1000(это значение ползунка "Текущий ММР") * 2 = 3000 руб

    b)3500 - 2500 * 2.5 = 2500 руб

    c)4500 - 3500 * 3.5 = 3500 руб

    d)(это значение ползунка "Конечный ММР")5000 - 4500 * 5.5 = 2750 руб

    a + b + c + d = 11750 руб

    11750 / 4000 = ~ 2.9 (нашли средний коэффициент)

3)

Найдя средний коэффициент и нужную дистанцию, мы умножаем их и получаем сумму. Его я искал для того, что бы применить в логике PHP.
```

Буду рад любым советам и подсказкам, это не заказ, так-что спешить некуда, я учусь. Спасибо.

Comment: вы бы лучше текстом написали алгоритм ваших формул. Ибо пока что понятно что есть текущий рейтинг и желаемый. Что дальше происходит лучше описать в словесной форме.

Comment: зачем вам считать на php? посчитайте все на js и передайте готовый результат в php

Comment: @nueq Можно и так. Проблема не в том, на чем посчитать, а в том, как посчитать?

Comment: @teran Согласен, я дополнил.

Comment: `$e = $result` ;)

Comment: @teran я знаю, это просто проверка, смысл в том, что бы найти средний коэффициент, который уже можно умножить с дистанцией и получить итоговую сумму. По сути всё просто, но вот как задать логику, когда php нужно считать a + b + c + d коэффы, а когда только c + d к примеру. Ведь всё зависит от переданных значений ползунков, а они могут как охватывать все 4 диапазона, так и 1 или 2...

Comment: @teran То есть, если мне придет значение первого ползунка 4000 а второго 5500, в таком случае мне уже не надо брать все 4 диапазона для поиска общего коэффициента, а только нужно 2 последних. В ручном просчете это конечно легко, но мне ведь нужно написать скрипт, который будет это понимать сам)

Comment: А зачем хужен PHP? Что бы логику от пользователя прятать? Можно и в JS посчитать

Comment: @E_p конечно можно, кто с этим спорит? Я возможно так и сделаю, но это проблему не решит, к сожалению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без проверки на границы и валидацию на JS получиться :

https://jsfiddle.net/0ghrmo2t/2/

```
// Можно правила менять, как хочешь!
var limits = [
    {"lower": 0, "upper": 2499, "coef" : 2 },
    {"lower": 2500, "upper": 3499, "coef" : 2.5 },
    {"lower": 3500, "upper": 4499, "coef" : 3.5 },
    {"lower": 4500, "upper": 5500, "coef" : 5.5 }
];

function getCoef(cVal, nVal) {
    var diff = nVal - cVal;
    var tmp = 0;

    limits.forEach(function (val) {

        // вне диапазона, не считаем.
        if (cVal > val.upper || nVal < val.lower) {
           return;
        }

        // Сколько попало в диапазон.
        var l = Math.max (cVal, val.lower - 1);
        var u = Math.min (nVal, val.upper);

        tmp += (u-l) * val.coef;
    });

    //console.log(tmp, tmp/diff);

    // Можно вернуть сумму.
    // return tmp;

    // или коэффициент
    return tmp/diff;
}

getCoef(2400, 3500);
getCoef(1000, 5000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, завтра обязательно попробую! :)